# Method not found: Void RestSharp.RestClient..ctor(System.String)

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

My .Net 7 C# application is given this error.
Sometimes it's not happend

logcenter log:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient..ctor(System.String)'.
> at .....service.http.HttpCommunication.HttpAsync(Method httpVerb, String hostUrl, Dictionary`2 headers, Object requestObject, Func`2 logFunction)

I'm  using RestSharp (110.2.0).

API communication discarted.
HttpRequest contruction discarted.

Comment: No @Progman , not just clean and rebluid missing dependency. My internal business dependency named "(my-company).service.http.HttpCommunication" was in a diferent version of RestSharp then my main project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, sometimes this happens and it appears that RestSharp has removed a method or constructor that is affecting backwards compatibility here.

I believe that the problem is because the two RestSharp versions are different in each dependency. I don't know of any solution or workaround, but I'd be glad to hear if anyone's aware of one.